# Usando duas opções simultaneamente JQueryUI Dialog Widgets

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Estou tentando implamentar o Widget Dialog do JQuery-UI para que toda a tela (e mais) seja completamente populada por Dialogs de diferentes tamanhos (width) e em diferentes posições (position).

Porém estou enfrentando dois problemas:

1) Não consigo setar as duas opções no JQuery UI. Ou aceita uma ou aceita a outra. O código que estou usando é esse:

```
  $( function() {
    $( "#lub" ).dialog({
      position: { my: "center top", at: "left top+150", of: window }
      width: 500        
   });
} );
```

Mesmo se eu der uma solução "macarrônica" para o problema ainda tem o outro problema:

2) Não consigo fazer aparecer o Widget Dialog fora da área de visualização da página. Não há numero que eu informe que faça com que a janela apareça aonde eu queo. O código da outra janela ficou assim:

```
  $( function() {
    $( "#rank" ).dialog({
        position: { my: "left top", at: "left top+1530", of: window }

    });
  } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já consegui resolver parte do problema. Aprendi como fazer para usar duas opções. Basta usar a vírgula como o exemplo abaixo:

```
  $( function() {
    $( "#rank" ).dialog({
        width: 500,
        autoOpen: true,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        position: { my: "left top", at: "left top+1530", of: window }

    });
  } );
```

Agora só falta descobrir como faz para o "position" funcionar em qualquer lugar da página.